# Phone suddenly not receiving notifications

Tags: android, notifications, xiaomi

Using Xiamoi Redmi3 I never had this issue until today.
I get notifications from snapchat, slack and messenger just fine until to this day where I was playing an app game and noticed my phone suddenly stopped giving me notifications..

- They are running in the background
- Notifications are Enabled for these apps
- Battery optimization for apps is disabled
- Memory Optimization (dev tool) is disabled
- "do not disturb" is not on

I really need this to get working, been googling desperately for hours reading same threads over and over without any progress.. Of course I've tried to restart the phone.

Please and thank you most sincerely in advance!
- P

Comment: I've followed every step here too
http://innov8tiv.com/fix-miui-8-push-notifications-not-working-problem/
http://en.miui.com/thread-454319-1-1.html

I'm so damn frustrated..!

Comment: Is backing up data and doing a factory reset a possibility? It's pretty quick to do and could solve, I'd give that a shot...

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming

Comment: @PJohanson Check if you get notification from one of them for example `slack` when it is in foreground. If so, there is a problem with your settings. Tell the result and if it was the case I can help you with it.

Comment: @merka thanks for the tip, i tried having the app active but still no actual notificaiton. However, in snapchat, you can have the GPS active and it does give this solid notification "your place has been identified" with snapchat logo as notice, not sure if related..

Comment: @PJohanson No, it is a local notification not a push notification. Can you ask someone to message you and test if you get notification when your app is in foreground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone ever would come across this, it's a bug in MIUI 8.
Temporare solution is to disable all notifications in the settings, and only enabling the ones you'd like to have. Otherwise, upgrade!